# exercise on multivariate normal random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

The following problem is from Tijms's *Understanding Probability*.

> The annual rates of return on the three stocks A, B, and C have a
>   trivariate normal distribution. The rate of return on stock A has
>   expected value 7.5% and standard deviation 7%, the rate of return on
>   stock B has expected value 10% and standard deviation 12%, and the
>   rate of return on stock C has expected value 20% and standard
>   deviation 18%. The correlation coefficient of the rates of return on
>   stocks A and B is 0.7, the correlation coefficient is -0.5 for the
>   stocks A and C, and the correlation coefficient is -0.3 for the stocks
>   B and C.
>
> An investor has \$100,000 in cash. Any cash that is not invested in
>   the three stocks will be put in a riskless asset that offers an annual
>   interest rate of 5%.
>
> (a) Suppose the investor puts \$20,000 in stock
>   A, \$20,000 in stock B, \$40,000 in stock C, and \$20,000 in the
>   riskless asset. What are the expected value and the standard deviation
>   of the portfolio’s value next year?
>
> (b) Can you find a portfolio whose
>   risk is smaller than the risk of the portfolio from Question (a) but
>   whose expected return is not less than that of the portfolio from
>   Question (a)?

My attempt.

(a) We would like to know the expected value of the random variable:
$$
  X = \frac15 A + \frac15 B + \frac25 C + \frac15 D,
$$
where we know that $E(D) = 0.05$, $\sigma_D = 0$, and $A,B,C$ have a trivariate normal distribution with mean vector:
$$
  \mu = (0.075, 0.1, 0.2)
$$
and covariance matrix
$$
  \mathbf{C} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \left(\frac{0.07}{0.075}\right)^2 & 0.7 & -0.5 \\
  0.7 & \left(\frac{0.12}{0.1}\right)^2 & -0.3 \\
  -0.5 & -0.3 & \left(\frac{0.18}{0.2}\right)^2
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

If A, B, and C were independent, I guess that by the central limit theorem we would have that $X$ has a normal distribution with mean
$$
  \mu_X=\frac{0.075}{5} + \frac{0.1}{5} + \frac{2\cdot 0.18}{5} + \frac{0.05}{5}
$$
and variance
$$
\sigma^2_X = \frac15 \left(\frac{0.07}{0.075}\right)^2 + \frac15 \left(\frac{0.12}{0.1}\right)^2 + \frac25 \left(\frac{0.18}{0.2}\right)^2,
$$
but in this case I am unsure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance of the random variables X and Y in terms of the correlation coefficient and standard deviation is $cov(X,Y)=\rho_{X,Y}\cdot \sigma_X\cdot \sigma_Y$ and not the other way round. That means that the variance-covariance matrix is

$$
  \mathbf{C} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.07^2 & 0.7\cdot 0.07\cdot 0.12 & -0.5\cdot 0.07\cdot 0.18 \\
   0.7\cdot 0.07\cdot 0.12& 0.12^2 &  -0.3\cdot 0.12\cdot 0.18 \\
  -0.5\cdot 0.07\cdot 0.18 & -0.3\cdot 0.12\cdot 0.18 & 0.18^2
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

And the Variance of the weighted sum (portfolio) is $Var\left( \frac15 A + \frac15 B + \frac25 C + \frac15 D \right)$

$=\frac{1}{25}\cdot Var(A)+\frac{1}{25}\cdot Var(B)+\frac{4}{25}\cdot Var(C)+2\cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot  cov(A,B)$

$+2\cdot  \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{5}\cdot  cov(A,C)+2\cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{5}\cdot cov(B,C)$

We don´t have to regard $D$ here, since $Var(D)=cov(D,X)=0$, where $X\in \{A,B,C\}$

**Remark:**

Your calculation for the expected value and my calculation for the variance refer to the $\texttt{return rate}$ of the portfolio.

To obtain the expectation of the $\texttt{portfolio´s value}$ you multiply your result by $100,000$ and then add   $100,000$. If you want the variance of the portfolio you multiply my result by $100,000^2$

Comment: Thanks. I see now that a way to see the variance result would be: let $\mathbf{X}=(\frac15,\frac15,\frac25)$, then $\mathrm{Var}(\frac15 A+\frac15 B+\frac25 C) = \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: @J.D. That´s perfectly true.